# GLSL Normals not transforming propertly

Tags: opengl, glsl, transformation, normals

I've been stuck on this problem for two days. I've read many articles about transforming normals, but I'm just totaly stuck.
I understand choping off W component for "turning off" translation, and doing inverse/traspose transformation for non-uniform scaling problem, but my bug seems to be from a different source.

So, I've imported a simple ball into OpenGL. Only transformation that I'm applying is rotation over time. But when my ball rotates, the illuminated part of the ball moves around just as it would if direction light direction was changing.

I just can't figure out what is the problem. Can anyone help me with this?

Here's the GLSL code:

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 440 core

uniform mat4 World, View, Projection;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;

layout(location = 1) in vec3 VertexColor;

layout(location = 2) in vec3 VertexNormal;

out vec4 Color;
out vec3 Normal;

void main()
{
    Color = vec4(VertexColor, 1.0);

    vec4 n = World * vec4(VertexNormal, 0.0f);
    Normal = n.xyz;

    gl_Position = Projection * View * World * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 440 core

uniform vec3 LightDirection = vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
uniform vec3 LightColor = vec3(1f);

in vec4 Color;
in vec3 Normal;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    diffuse = max(0.0, dot(normalize(-LightDirection), normalize(Normal)));
    vec4 scatteredLight = vec4(LightColor * diffuse, 1.0f);

    FragColor = min(Color * scatteredLight, vec4(1.0));

}
```

And here is demonstration of the problem:
[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand what the problem is. Aren't different parts of the ball supposed to be visible by the light as it rotates?

Comment: I updated the question. As you can see now the different area is being illuminated like the light direction is changing (but it is not). And I wanna point it out, it is not moving like ball rotation (as it would if no transformation was applied).

Comment: I assume you do not care about the quantization errors (the square gradients)? I cannot tell if that is an artifact from image compression or your actual rendering, though I am leaning towards image compression because I cannot see anything unusual about your vertex shader.

Comment: That said, I think you want view-space normals, not world-space (so multiply by `view * world` instead of `world`). Your light direction appears to be fixed in view-space facing down the Z-axis.

Comment: -1 for "debug my code" question.  Particularly since the issue turned out to be in code not even presented here (or in the self-answer), so this question becomes completely worthless for the site's Q&A archive.

Answer (score 2):

Andon is making the correct assumption I believe. Specifically, the `n` vector in the vertex shader should be assigned as `View * World * vec4(VertexNormal, 0.0f);` so that view space normals are used in both the position and the vertex normal computations.

One additional suggestion: the `Normalize(Normal)` execution may be more efficient if it is applied to each vertex normal before the results are used in the fragment shader.  Try assigning `Normal = Normalize(n.xyz)` in the vertex shader right after the view space normal assignment...then take it out of the diffuse shading line in the frag.

Basically, my thought is vertex normalization can be parallelized in the vertex shader context, and it may not happen parallelized during the fragment shader.

Either case, the above solutions should make the sphere shading invariant to rotation which was your problem in the first place.

Comment: But my light is not in the view space coordinates. I wanted it to go in direction of world Z axis. Anyway, i managed to find where was the problem. It was actually in the application, while I was parsing fbx I didn't fetch normals properly. Thanks for normalize suggestion, I'll do it.

Comment: You *can* get better perf by putting the normalization in the vertex shader, but be aware that you probably *will* get artefacts too, as normalization doesn't linearly interpolate.  But by all means experiment, as the artefacts may not be objectionable, or even noticeable, depending on your geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Found where was the problem. I just didn't fetch normals properly while parsing fbx. Now everything works fine.